# Why the singular points of an algebraic variety are those at which all the partial derivatives simultaneously vanish?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Why are the singular points of an algebraic variety those at which all the partial derivatives simultaneously vanish?

I can't understand why that is, and I need a proof and/or an intuitive explanation of it.

Comment: Some take this as the definition, what is your definition of a singular point ?

Comment: For taking this as a definition, there must be some reason. Unfortunately, I can't provide any other definition at my level of comprehension.

Comment: Why close this question ? It is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try reading Garrity et al's *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem-Solving Approach* which gives a good discussion of the motivation for this definition for the simplest  case of algebraic curves.

Basically the idea is that when all of the partial derivatives vanish, it becomes impossible to give a well-defined tangent object which gives meaningful information at the point.

For example, when all of the partial derivatives of an algebraic curve vanish, then any tangent vector at the point would just be the zero vector. However, the zero vector has no direction (it is in fact the only vector which does not have any direction), so thus there is no way to define a tangent direction at the point. Without a tangent direction, there is much less information at the point than elsewhere on the curve, where a notion of "best approximation by a line" is meaningful.

Similar ideas would come into play for higher-dimensional varieties I imagine.

Comment: Here is another answer to [the question](https://www.quora.com/Why-the-singular-points-of-an-algebraic-variety-are-those-at-which-all-the-partial-derivatives-simultaneously-vanish?__snid3__=392238566&__nsrc__=2&__filter__) .

It says that if a partial derivative is different to zero on a certain variable on a certain point, you can express this variable in terms of the others around the point. It may not be possible to express any variables in terms of the others if all derivatives are zero, but an example is given at the end where it is possible.